# Convert BooleanProperty to StringProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My model

```
class Sale(db.Model):

#Sale info
s_date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True )

#s_deliverstatus = db.StringProperty(default='False')
s_deliverstatus = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
s_profit = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
s_remind = db.BooleanProperty(required=False,default=False)
```

with thousands of record.

I need to convert `s_deliverstatus` type from Bool to String, so my new Model is

```
class Sale(db.Model):

#Sale info
s_date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True )

#s_deliverstatus = db.StringProperty(default='False')
s_deliverstatus = db.StringProperty(default='False')
s_profit = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
s_remind = db.BooleanProperty(required=False,default=False)
```

because I want `s_deliverstatus` to be able to receive 3 values: 'True', 'False', 'Runing'

Only modifying the Sale model does not work. It returns error for old entities

What is the safe way to convert old `s_deliverstatus` (BooleanProperty) from False (bool) to 'False' (string), and True(bool) to 'True' (string) and store in new `s_deliverstatus` (StringProperty)?

Comment: Does the property have to keep the same name? If not You can add a new property and use that instead. That way you can keep your existing data without any major changes. Otherwise you will have to copy your db to a temporary one, create a new schema, then copy it back one by one into the new schema. If you have to do this id recommend backing it up and doing it on a local machine then upload it back up.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create your own type of property which recognizes both:

```
class BooleanToStringProperty(db.StringProperty):
  def make_value_from_datastore(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, bool):
      return "True" if value else "False"
    return super(self, BooleanToStringProperty).make_value_from_datastore(value)

class Sale(db.Model):
  # ...
  s_deliverstatus = BooleanToStringProperty(default='False')
```

Basically what this does is when the property sees a boolean value when returned from the Datastore it converts it to a string. Otherwise, it just passes it through. New puts will use a string value, but it would be able to read boolean values from the Datastore.

**Important**: If you want to query on this property for True/False values, you would have to write two queries, one where the value == 'True'`and another where`value == True`. (This would require a little more work since you need to have your model allow querying for a boolean even though it's a string).